# Echonest query by country is not working

Tags: echonest

i'm using Echonest in order to make an query for the TopSinger in specific country. The problem is that some 'not popular' artist are returned anyway. For example, in Italy "Armando" is on of the top-100 artist. But this artist is now popular in Italy, also is totally unknow artist.

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/search?api_key=xxx&format=json&start=0&results=100&rank_type=relevance&sort=familiarity-desc&artist_start_year_after=1950&artist_location=Italy

At this point i'm not sure about the accuracy of EchoNest.
Somebody can explain if i'm making something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No you are doing nothing wrong. It is just the result of Echonest's algorithm

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile?api_key=xxx&id=AR22QZN1187FB4D4C0&bucket=familiarity

Armando's familiarity is currently calculated as 0.563938 deserves that rank according to this number :)

Comment: ok, but this is a wrong data that in theory should not be in Italy since 'Armando' is totally not know in that country.